# Counting clicks and difficulty menu in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm really hopeless with flash but my course decided it was a great idea to introduce it so here I am struggling for days. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong please???

I'm trying to make a counting game where the menu has 3 difficulties: easy medium and hard. For easy, I have to generate random coins from 5-10, medium 10-15 and hard 15-20.

Also I'm trying to have the coins counted so if the right number generated is reached a message pops up saying 'congrats'

this is what i have so far..:

```
import fl.motion.MotionEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var Count:Number = 0;

coinz.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler_3);

function fl_MouseClickHandler_3(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("Mouse clicked");
}

var clickCount:int= 0;

btnnumb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,addClick);

function addClick(evt:MouseEvent):void{
    clickCount++;
}
textarea.text="SCORE:"+clickCount.toString();

var minLimit:uint = 5;
var maxLimit:uint = 10;
var range:uint = maxLimit - minLimit;
var myNum:Number = Math.ceil(Math.random()*range) + minLimit;
trace(myNum);


var low:Number = 1;
var high:Number = 5;
var result:Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 + high - low)) + low

stop();
```

Comment: You need to point out the actual problem you're having.  What part isn't working as you expect?

Comment: I'm trying to get the code for counting the clicks to work. And would like extra help with creating a difficulty menu as I have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: You should put this line:  `textarea.text="SCORE:"+clickCount.toString();` inside your `addClick` function (right after `clickount++`) - otherwise the text box will not update.

Answer (score 1):

You are a bit unorganized.
If you want to follow the best practice then you should forget about timeline *(use classes)*
But, you are in timeline... here is also a good practice to put all your *variables* and *events* declarations in the top of the script, and your functions after;
For random between 2 numbers you can use a function `rand(min, max)` is better.

so you can do something like this:

```
import fl.motion.MotionEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

stop();

//variables name should start with lower case letter by convention
var count      : Number = 0;  
var clickCount : int    = 0;
var randNumber : int    = 0;  //define understandable variables name (not myNum)

//constant variables should be in upper case and words sparated by underline
var MIN_RAND_LIMIT  : uint   = 5;
var MAX_RAND_LIMIT  : uint   = 10;

coinz.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onCoinzClick);
btnnumb.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addClick); //again 'btnnumb' is bad name

function onCoinzClick(e:MouseEvent) : void {
    trace("Mouse clicked");
}

function addClick(e:MouseEvent) : void {
    clickCount++;
    //don't need toString in concatenation
    textarea.text="SCORE:" + clickCount; 
}

function rand(min:Number, max:Number) : Number {
    return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min);
}

//test
randNumber = rand(MIN_RAND_LIMIT, MAX_RAND_LIMIT);
trace(randNumber);

///
///the rest logic of your game...
///
```

Try as much as possible to be organized and you will find it more easy to work and to get better...

Now regarding your game here are some hints:

- in first frame make 3 buttons (easy, medium, hard)
- when the button is click modify the min and max, depends on the clicked button and go to next frame
- in the second frame you will have your game play logic...

Hope it helps.

Comment: Constant variables should be constant. `const MIN_RAND_LIMIT`

Comment: look at his scenario, he wants to modify that variables from the 1st frame according to chosen difficulty. So I don't really know how it works in the timeline if they are const, but you're right about const...